# How can I add a negative value to all the cells in column with alphabetical content?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

How can I add a "-" sign to the beginning of every cell in google spreadsheets?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

To add the - sign or any charterer in spreadsheet cell you just 
1.add it once in the desired cell, 
2.select the cell until you see a cross sign in the left bottom corner of the selected cell.
3.Drag down that cross to any all cells  you want . 
4.release the mouse and you will see the character is copied along to all selected cells

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you! 
But how can I perform the same operation to add minus sign to cells with alphabetic value in them?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at CONCATENATE:

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094123

```
=CONCATENATE(string1, [string2, ...])
```

String1 could be "-" or "- " and string2 would be your alphabetic values.